# EditValue return comma instead period

Tags: vb.net, format

i using TextBox for my form which contain decimal values.

`TextEdit.EditValue = 0.4`

Because i'm in Indonesia and my computer decimal setting is `,`, when i call `TextEdit.EditValue` it'll return `0,4` instead `0.4` , it will be a problem when i insert to database because `TextEdit.EditValue` use comma not period. How can i change this?

Also i dont want to change my client format setting. Can i change global setting or something to return the `TextEdit.EditValue` to `0.4`?

Comment: EditValue is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.TextBox. Are you using a DevExpress TextEdit which does have an EditValue property?

Comment: my bad, it's textedit

Answer (score 0):

So you are using a DevExpress TextEdit.

The EditValue is of type Object. When you retrieve the EditValue, hover your cursor over TextEdit1.EditValue and see whether the assigned object type is String or Decimal. I suspect it is Decimal in which case the object is of the type that you want it to be and the fact that it is displaying "0,4" doesn't matter. Try casting it and see whether the compiler throws an error or correctly assigns 0.4 to the myDecimal variable

```
Dim myDecimal As Decimal = CType(TextEdit1.EditValue, Decimal)
```

Comment: mydecimal will return 0,4 , when you try inserting to database it'll return 0.00 (must replace comma to period first and only work if computer client using comma)

Comment: I am perplexed that CType("0,4", Decimal) returns 4D. I thought that that would either have returned 0.4D or thrown an error.

Comment: Are you saying that if the user enters "0.4" into the TextEdit that the EditValue is returning "0,4"? Why don't you use the Text property of the TextEdit instead? If the user enters "0.4" into the TextEdit then you can be sure that CType(TextEdit1.Text, Decimal) will return 0.4D.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

NewDataPeriod = DATA.Replace(",",".")

Change all Comma in your data to Period

Comment: It's seem fix the problem, but not that i wanted. i want to change .editvalue to period by default.